# Java Command line argument parsing issue using Apache commons library

Tags: java, command-line-arguments, apache-commons-cli

I am using Apache commons basic/gnu parser to parse command line options as shown below.

```
import org.apache.commons.cli.CommandLine;
import org.apache.commons.cli.CommandLineParser;
import org.apache.commons.cli.DefaultParser;
import org.apache.commons.cli.GnuParser;


    CommandLineParser parser = new GnuParser();
    CommandLine cmd = parser.parse(options, args);
    System.out.println(cmd.getOptionValue("iplist"));
```

I am invoking program using below mention list of parameters.

```
 java -jar myjar.jar --iplist 160.1.1.1,3009 160.1.1.1,3003 160.1.1.1,3004
```

Out put i am getting is just first IP address, how can i get all three IP addresses with port which are passed as an argument to --iplist variable?

Here are the options i am using.

```
    options.addOption("h", "help", false, "show help.");
    options.addOption("iplst","iplist", true, "Provide name of server where program can listen IP,PORT");

         CommandLineParser parser = new GnuParser();
         CommandLine cmd = null;
      try {
       cmd = parser.parse(options, args);

       if (cmd.hasOption("h"))
        help();

       if (cmd.hasOption("iplist")) {
        System.out.println( "Using cli argument --server=" + cmd.getOptionValue("iplistr"));
//Code here
       }
```

Comment: have you tried  `java -jar myjar.jar --iplist "160.1.1.1,3009 160.1.1.1,3003 160.1.1.1,3004"` ?

Comment: Please also show how you define the `options`

Comment: @centic I just added the code for options.

Comment: @ymonad double quote solution is working but i can't force user to pass arguments in quotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [OptionBuilder](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-cli/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/cli/OptionBuilder.html) like:

```
Option iplist = OptionBuilder
                .withArgs() // option has unlimited argument
                .withDescription("Provide name of server where program can listen IP,PORT")
                .withLongOption("iplist") // means start with -- 
                .create()
```

Also look at:

https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-cli/usage.html

http://apache-commons.680414.n4.nabble.com/cli-Example-using-of-option-with-two-mandatory-arguments-td3321524.html

Comment: withArgs method is deprecated   Option server = Option.builder("r").argName("ipl").longOpt("iplist")
         .hasArg().desc("Name of server where decoder or collector can listen IP,PORT")
         .required().build();

Comment: Or it is possible if i give values of iplist two times and get value out of it . java -jar myjar.jar --iplist 160.1.1.1,3009  --iplist 160.1.1.1,3010 ?

Comment: I am not sure but I guess it is a valid usage so you can try. But be careful about `hasArg()` and `hasArgs()`. Use second for multiple arguments.